# Outlook 2010: End recurring task without regenerating original task

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have an Outlook 2010 task that was created in 2015, set to recur weekly. I no longer need this task. I want to end date it with today's date and keep all previous records that I had completed this task. If I change the end date ("end by" today's date), Outlook will recreate this task. How do I end date it and keep the task history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to export your recurring tasks to CSV or Excel format and then import back into Outlook. See [Changing the End Date on Recurring Appointments](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/changing-date-recurring-appointments/).

Comment: Can you include the relevant information from your link here?